# Element filtering on load

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm filtering data on my website using data-filter.

Everything works fine, but I would like to show on load items with specific attibutes.

For example I would like to show on load only green objects. Not as a default show all.

http://jsfiddle.net/joshvogt/UybPY/

HTML:

```
<section>
  <a href="#" data-filter="all" tabindex="-1">ALL</a> 
  <a href="#" data-filter="red" tabindex="-1">RED</a>
  <a href="#" data-filter="green" tabindex="-1">GREEN</a>
  <a href="#" data-filter="blue" tabindex="-1">BLUE</a>

<div data-filter="red"></div>
<div data-filter="blue"></div>
<div data-filter="red"></div>
<div data-filter="blue"></div>
<div data-filter="green"></div>
<div data-filter="red"></div>
<div data-filter="red"></div>
<div data-filter="red"></div>
<div data-filter="blue"></div>
<div data-filter="green"></div>
<div data-filter="blue"></div>
<div data-filter="green"></div>
<div data-filter="green"></div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
section{
  display:block;
  float:left;
  border:2px solid green;
  min-height:300px;
  width:100%;
  border-radius:4px;
}

a{
  display:block;
  float:left;
  width:25%;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-align:center;
  padding:5px 0;
  color:white;
  background:#1271C7;
}

div{
 display:block;
 float:left;
 height:40px;
 width:40px;
```

How to show only green elements on load:

```
div[data-filter="green"]{
  background:green;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

if i have understood you correctly then you need this

```css
section {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid green;
  min-height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  color: white;
  background: #1271C7;
}
div,
a[data-filter="all"]:focus ~  div,
a[data-filter="red"]:focus ~ div[data-filter="red"],
a[data-filter="blue"]:focus ~ div[data-filter="blue"] {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: all .8s linear;
  -moz-transition: all .8s linear;
  -o-transition: all .8s linear;
  -ms-transition: all .8s linear;
  transition: all .8s linear;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
div[data-filter="red"] {
  background: red;
}
div[data-filter="green"] {
  background: green;
}
div[data-filter="blue"] {
  background: blue;
}
a:focus[data-filter] {
  opacity: .8;
  outline: none;
}

div:not([data-filter="green"]),
a[data-filter="red"]:focus ~ div:not([data-filter="red"]),
a[data-filter="green"]:focus ~ div:not([data-filter="green"]),
a[data-filter="blue"]:focus ~ div:not([data-filter="blue"]) {
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<section> <a href="#" data-filter="all" tabindex="-1">ALL</a>  <a href="#" data-filter="red" tabindex="-1">RED</a>
  <a href="#" data-filter="green" tabindex="-1">GREEN</a>
  <a href="#" data-filter="blue" tabindex="-1">BLUE</a>

  <div data-filter="red"></div>
  <div data-filter="blue"></div>
  <div data-filter="red"></div>
  <div data-filter="blue"></div>
  <div data-filter="green"></div>
  <div data-filter="red"></div>
  <div data-filter="red"></div>
  <div data-filter="red"></div>
  <div data-filter="blue"></div>
  <div data-filter="green"></div>
  <div data-filter="blue"></div>
  <div data-filter="green"></div>
  <div data-filter="green"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: how can we  apply the class using css3 selector -                a[data-filter="blue"]:focus ~ div:not([data-filter="blue"]) {
  applyClass Here
} .. This will shorten the program even more

Answer (score 1):

Hide all by default, and show green only:

```
div[data-filter] {
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
}
div[data-filter="green"] {
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UybPY/719/

Answer (score 0):

It's something like this:

```
$('div:not([data-filter="green"])').hide();
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lbw7pwwe/).

Answer (score 0):

on document ready use as follows

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('section div:not([data-filter="green"])').hide();
});
```

on load it will look for the div's having the attribute "data-filter" with green and rest will be hidden

this is appropriate

Answer (score 0):

Try it....

```
$("div[data-filter!='green']").each(function (i, el) {
     //It'll be an array of elements
    $(this).hide();
 });
```

DEMO:http://jsfiddle.net/UybPY/717/